# Updating modal body and modal footer using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal which gets its content dynamically. The content goes to two divisions `modal-body` and `modal-footer`.
But the problem is only `modal-body` is changed dynamically and `modal-footer` remains the same.

This is the snippet of html code(includes bootstrap classes):

```
    <a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#removeCandidateModal' onclick="removeCandidate()">Remove</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="removeCandidateModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Remove Candidate</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="remove-candidates-modal-body">
    
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer" id="remove-candidates-modal-footer">
    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The javascript part:

```
function removeCandidate() {
 let id="45678";
 let name="Bob";
 let election_type="BHVC";
        document.getElementById('remove-candidates-modal-body').innerHTML = '<p>Are you sure you want to remove the following candidate<br> Candidate Name:' + name +
            '<br>Candidate ID:' + id +
            '<br>Elections:' + election_type + '</p>';
        document.getElementById('remove-candidates-modal-footer').innerHTML = '<div class="modal-footer">' +
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>\n' +
            '                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick=removeCandidateYes("' + id + '")>Yes</button>\n' +
            '            </div>';
    }
```

The current output is this(it doesnt show the footer elements):

[image: output]

Comment: sorry..typo mistake

Comment: And where you define  `tempRes`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/DTcHh/93833/)**.

You are so close, your code should work fine if you just remove the extra div :

```
<div class="modal-footer">
```

So the appended html to the footer, should be  :

```
document.getElementById('remove-candidates-modal-footer').innerHTML = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>' +
      '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick=removeCandidateYes("' + id + '")>Yes</button>';
```

```js
function removeCandidate() {
  let id = "45678";
  let name = "Bob";
  let election_type = "BHVC";

  document.getElementById('remove-candidates-modal-body').innerHTML = '<p>Are you sure you want to remove the following candidate<br> Candidate Name:' + name +
    '<br>Candidate ID:' +
    '<br>Elections:' + election_type + '</p>';
  document.getElementById('remove-candidates-modal-footer').innerHTML = '' +
    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>\n' +
    '                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick=removeCandidateYes("' + id + '")>Yes</button>';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#removeCandidateModal' onclick="removeCandidate()">Remove</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="removeCandidateModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Remove Candidate</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="remove-candidates-modal-body"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer" id="remove-candidates-modal-footer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `jQuery` the below should work

```js
$(function(){

var id="45678";
var name="Bob";
var election_type="BHVC";

        var modalBody = '<p>Are you sure you want to remove the following candidate<br> Candidate Name:' + name +
            '<br>Candidate ID:' + id +
            '<br>Elections:' + election_type + '</p>';
            
        var modalFooter = '<div class="modal-footer">' +
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>\n' +
            '                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick=removeCandidateYes("' + id + '")>Yes</button>\n' +
            '            </div>';
    

$(".modal-body").html("").html(modalBody);
$(".modal-footer").html("").html(modalFooter);
  $('#removeCandidateModal').modal('toggle');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#removeCandidateModal' onclick="removeCandidate()">Remove</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="removeCandidateModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Remove Candidate</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="remove-candidates-modal-body">

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer" id="remove-candidates-modal-footer">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: why is the .html() used 2 times?

Comment: @EverythinginoneChannel, Just it will clear any existing contents and append the new content. It is just an addition but not really necessary

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not working as you are trying to add another modal-footer class to an existing modal footer class

Try to replace with below code

```
document.getElementById('remove-candidates-modal-footer').innerHTML = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>\n' +
        '                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick=removeCandidateYes("' + id + '")>Yes</button>\n';
```